# C# Lazy property gets initialized on constructor

Tags: c#, properties, lazy-initialization

I have lazy command in my view model:

```
private ICommand _testCommand;
public ICommand TestCommand => _testCommand ?? (_testCommand = new Command(Test));
```

and for some reason it gets called and initialized on constructor.
This is constructor:

```
public TestViewModel(IMediator mediator, IDispatcherService dispatcherService, IGroupService groupService)
{
    _mediator = mediator;
    _dispatcherService = dispatcherService;
    _groupService = groupService;
}
```

Command is not bound in UI and it is not called from anywhere except unit tests in which this problem happens when view model is constructed that is before property gets called.

I tried putting break point on property and when it entered break point in Call Stack it showed that last one to call this property is [External Code] and before that is constructor.

Does anyone know what is actually happening here?

Comment: You probably have something reading this property. Either a "watch" in Visual Studio or something that inspects your class, in the context of the unit tests. 
May even be from the your IoC Container, if for some unknown reason, it tries to read all the properties of your class. 

If you really want to figure it out, put some logging/console output in the property's getter and remove, one by one, potential readers (The IoC container, unit test framework, the debugger/watch itself etc) and run your ctor. You should figure out who's the offender quickly enough.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you might consider using Lazy<>.

Comment: The debugger should help you out here. There is nothing in the constructor that could cause this.

Comment: Did you bind any UI to the property?